# Is there a shorter way than this to check values when using same Add form for Edit

Tags: codeigniter

I have the same code for an Add and an Edit form. Therefore in the controller I need a check to check if a) POST vars submitted (for saving), and if not then b) the original values (for editing) and if not then no value (blank for Adding). I put them in a $data array to pass to the view. Then in the form I can put:

```
value="<?php echo $member_id;?>"
```

So my question is, in Codeigniter is there a shorter way than the following to check if POST, then if not check if the original data exists, and if not then its nothing.

```
$data = array(
    'member_id' => ( isset($_POST['member_id']) ? $_POST['member_id']  : (isset($member->member_id ) ? $member->member_id : '') )
);
```

I know about set_value() but looks like that wont add in the current data when editing a form, so have not used that.

Comment: is something wrong with `set_value()`? the first parameter is the field name which will be filled up by post and the second parameter is the value you want if no post have been initiated.

Comment: Wouldn't work on its own. Still had to assign an empty variable for the Add form if no post or no data was passed. Although there's probably a way to use it and reduce the above code but it still needed to be part of a conditional with an empty value assigned if no value was retuned by set_value (because my view form has a variable in the field value, I get notices if this does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

You can allways make function for it.

```
function get_value_or_default($array, $key, $default) {
    return isset($array[$key] ? $array[$key] : 
        isset($default) ? $default : '';
}
```

Or even better:

```
function update_from_post($object) {
    $data = array();
    foreach ($object as $prop_name => value) {
        $value = get_value_or_default($_POST, $prop_name, $object->{$prop_name});
        $data[$prop_name] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I have used the first suggestion and works fine, because the second one wont set the value to blank for the Add form because the $object wont exist for Adding, so I get PHP Notices. (I am setting it to blank in the controller rather than do a check in the view form).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have different methods in the controller for create vs edit: (you can use the same view in different methods by specifying it in `$this->load->view()`):

Your create method would assume it was new, and always read the $_POST variables (if $_POST)

Your edit method would first load the object from the database, and then overwrite with $_POST variables if present.

Finally, CodeIgniter has the input helper:

```
$this->input->post('field_name');
```

returns `false` if that field is not in $_POST.

To use your code above:

**create**

```
$data = array(
    'member_id' => $this->input->post('member_id') ? $this->input->post('member_id') : '')
);
```

**edit**

```
$data = array(
    'member_id' => $this->input->post('member_id') ? $this->input->post('member_id') : $member->member_id )
);
```

Comment: Same method, sorry should have been more clear. Because the form is the same for both so submits same action.

Comment: A smarter way would be to keep the methods separately. Use the CodeIgniter form helper to solve the problem of the submit destination. Then one view can submit to multiple methods depending on the caller: 

`<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(), $attributes); ?>`

Comment: I understand but wanted to try the same method to reduce code. Seems to be working fine but thought the above lines were quite long when there's lots of values so think I'll try the functions posted in another reply. It's just half the code in an Add method would be the Edit method (although i could make a function) hence trying to have one method handle both. Seems to work ok.